# how to clearInterval function when it is defined in post ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to clearInterval `setInterval` function when it is defined in post `ajax` jquery.
it is working well when we define `setInterval` function outside of the post response but it is not working when we define at the response place as like as js code below:

```
 $.post("demo_test_post.php",
    {
      name:"m",
      city:"n"
    },
    function(data,status){
 var setInterval_d = setInterval(function(){
 // some code

}, 1000);

});

 clearInterval(setInterval_d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your interval variable outside of scope of post method and then just assign it to interval inside of the post method.

```js
var setInterval_d

$.post("demo_test_post.php",
    {
      name:"m",
      city:"n"
    },
    function(data,status){
       setInterval_d = setInterval(function(){
       // some code
       }, 1000);
    });

 clearInterval(setInterval_d);
```

Comment: i want switch from one interval to another interval and for this manner when i want to go new interval i want old interval break. it will done at the main part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to a variable outside some scope, you should put it in that scope:

```
var setInterval_d;
$.post("demo_test_post.php", {
  name:"m",
  city:"n"
}, function(data,status) {
  setInterval_d = setInterval(function() {
    // some code
  }, 1000);
});

if (setInterval_d) {
    clearInterval(setInterval_d);
}
```

Note: I'm not sure if it is just your example, but in this example the `setInterval_d` will always be `undefined` because it is executed before there is an answer of the `post`.

Comment: so you mean i cant break that interval as it is definde at the post scope!, i need globaly break all intervals that i want, but the problem is that i cant do that when it is defined in that post response scope

Comment: That's correct; you can't clear an interval that is not in scope. You can only access variables in your current scope. It doesn't have to be globally, you can define any variable you want, for example: `window.intervals = {}; window.intervals.setInterval_d = ...`